# To uncheck all checkboxes of an column in jqxGrid

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I have small table built using **jqxGrid**. The 1st column contains checkboxes like below:

[image]

**Expected result:**

1. On click of **Uncheck All**, need all these check-boxes to be un-checked like this:

[image]

2. On click of **remove** need to get data of checkbox selected rows.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='travelGrid'></div>
<br>
<button id="unselect">Unselect All</button>
```

Remove

**JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var travelGridSource = {
      localdata: [],
      datafields: [
           { name: 'isSelected', type: 'bool' },
           { name: 'Zipcode', type: 'number' },
           { name: 'TravelFee', type: 'number' }
      ],
      datatype: "array"
}

 
var travelFees = [
                { "isSelected": "true", "Zipcode": "001", "TravelFee": "25"},
                { "isSelected": "true", "Zipcode": "002", "TravelFee": "75"},
                { "isSelected": "false", "Zipcode": "003", "TravelFee": "75"},
                { "isSelected": "true", "Zipcode": "004", "TravelFee": "75" },
                { "isSelected": "false", "Zipcode": "004", "TravelFee": "75" }
 ];
 
 travelGridSource.localdata = travelFees;
 
                 $("#travelGrid").jqxGrid({
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '20%',
                    rowsheight: 29,
                    columnsheight: 29,
                    source: new $.jqx.dataAdapter(travelGridSource),
                    sortable: true,
                    columnsresize: true,
                    columnsmenu: false,
                    showsortcolumnbackground: false,
                    enablehover: false,
                    selectionmode: 'none',
                    scrollmode: 'logical',
                    theme: 'light',
                    rowdetails: true,
                    editable: true,
                    showrowdetailscolumn: false,
                    columns: [
                        { text: '', datafield: 'isSelected', width: '7%', align: 'center', columntype: 'checkbox', cellsalign: 'center', 'editable': true  },
                        { text: 'Zip', datafield: 'Zipcode', width: '15%', align: 'center', cellsalign: 'center', 'editable': false  },
                        { text: 'Travel Fee', datafield: 'TravelFee', width: '20%', align: 'center', cellsalign: 'center', cellsformat: 'c2'}
                    ]
                });
 });
 
 
 $('#unselect').click(function(){
    // Do something here
 });

 $('#remove').click(function(){
    // Do something here
 });
```

Have surfed lot and the documentation too but no use. Couldn't able to append **fiddle** link, So pasted the **fiddle URL** as code:

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/75zrfko0/25/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to take your unselect click event in scope of of jQuery document due to you local scope of dataset.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //unselect onclick event listener
})
```

Then on click of that button you have to update that local dataset from which you are adding flags for checkboxes & lastly have to update source in jqxGrid that you have taken.

```
    $('#unselect').click(function(){
    // Do something here
     travelFees = travelFees.map((obj) => {
        obj.isSelected = "false";
            return {...obj};
     })
     travelGridSource.localdata = travelFees;
     $("#travelGrid").jqxGrid({source: new $.jqx.dataAdapter(travelGridSource)});
 });
```

I haven't fully gone through API for JQXWiget but there can be a method to update local dataset please follow the below link,

1. https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/checkboxcolumn.htm

Comment: Can you give solution for  2nd question?

Comment: @Shankar you can use filter method to fetch the selected checkbox on remove event from you local data set. Just pass filter of obj.isSelected === "true" in array.filter method.

Comment: This works fine on grid load but after grid load if i select other checkboxes that won't be updated(i,e to travelGridSource) right?

Comment: you have to add on check property as mentioned in example link above in my answer.

Comment: Please guide me: How can i call a function/method on click of checkbox.

Comment: @Shankar here is an example in js fiddle for cell selection you can handle your checkbox click event here http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/HB3Cb/  if needed further help please open a discussion. I will answer it when I get free.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226374/discussion-between-shankar-and-krishank-tripathi).

Comment: I know how to call a function on **cell click**, But i want to call a function onclick of checkbox which is present inside the cell.